# Suggestions to write my first application for ROS?

Tags: ros, package, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Since I will have to do a project with ROS further down the road and I just finished the tutorials, I was wondering for any suggestions referring what could be a 'simple to implement' application I could write for a ROS package to get used to its environment.
My project will be related to position, lasers and camera, so if it has something to do with it, even better. I will be only able to test it with stage/rviz (not a real robot, I mean).

Any suggestions are welcome,
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11418/suggestions-to-write-my-first-application-for-ros?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't really have an idea for a simple application right now, but here is how you can set up a simulation environment that is "almost" like a real robot.

Instead of stage, you should also have a look at Gazebo (especially if you want to experiment with camera images). If you want to keep it simple, I would recommend looking at the [Turtlebot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot); it is very well-supported in Gazebo, so it's almost like working with a real robot, and less daunting than the PR2.

You can use the `turtlebot_empty_world.launch` launch file from the [turtlebot_gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_gazebo) package, or use the following modified launch file to give you a more interesting world:

```
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-u $(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/wg_collada.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/robot.launch"/>
</launch>
```

This gives you a fake laser scan(*) on the `/scan` topic ("fake" because it's computed from the Kinect data), camera data on the subtopics of `/camera/`, and position information via the `/odom` topic and via the [tf transform](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) from `odom_combined` to `base_link`.

(*) be aware of [this bug](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/84), though.

**Edit:** Okay, so what about this simple application: Write a behavior that makes the robot randomly explore its environment while avoiding to run into obstacles. You would have to subscribe to the `scan` topic for obstacle detection and publish messages to the `cmd_vel` topic to make the robot move.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-10-11**:
Yes, the scenario I described is of course possible with stage, but I have no experience with that. If you have a specific question about setting up stage, it's probably best to ask a new question about that.

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2011-10-10**:
What about doing this with stage? Is it possible? (even if I wouldn't be able to experiment with camera capabilities) The reason being that currently my workstation its not powerful enough (once I tried with the pr2 model and it stutters really really badly).

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-10-06**:
Yeah, I've used that trick in the past but in this case, no such directory gets created.  Even "roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch" generates the same error so I have submitted a ticket (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5195).

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-10-06**:
When Gazebo refuses to start, I usually do a `rm -rf /tmp/gazebo-*` and try again. Does Gazebo work for you with other launch files? If this doesn't help, it's probably best to submit a ticket or ask a new question here, so that the Gazebo gurus become aware of it.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-10-06**:
Hi Martin--I wanted to try your suggestion myself but when launching the above file I get the following error when running the latest Electric debian packages under Ubuntu 10.04: "loading model xml from ros parameter gazebo: /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLSupport.cpp:56: virtual void Ogre::GLSupport::initialiseExtensions(): Assertion `pcVer && "Problems getting GL version string using glGetString"' failed.
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 30131, exit code -6]."  Any thoughts for a fix or should I submit a ticket?